# Rounding up c# giving wrong answer

Tags: c#, .net, math, floating-point, double

I am programming a stocks/production program for a school project (bike factory) and I have to round some numbers up such as the bikes that have to be produced (due to fallout it are doubles).

If I use the following code:

```
double test = Math.Ceiling(100 * 1.09);

label75.Text = Convert.ToString(test);
```

I get as an answer 110, but that's not right, it should be 109 (9% of 100). Although it seems to work with values below 9%.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: `label75`. Please tell me that's not a real variable name.

Comment: This question has been asked probably hundreds of times on this site. Maybe thousands. Please also read: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: give the guy a break. It's a school project, not a code review.

Comment: @David bad habits learned early are hard to break. Also, having to maintain a code base where `strSqlStatement44` is an actual variable name tends to put you on a hair trigger (no, I am not making that up).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`double`s and `float`s are binary floating point types. This means they cannot precisely represent many decimal numbers (like `1.09`). This leads to some subtle round off errors. In your case 100 * 1.09 actually results in a number very slightly larger than 109, so the `Ceiling` function correctly rounds it up to the nearest integer, 110.

Change it to a `decimal` and you'll get the result you expect:

```
decimal test = Math.Ceiling(100 * 1.09m); // 109
```

Note the `m` in `1.09m` identifies it as a `decimal` literal. This works because the `decimal` type is specifically designed to represent decimal numbers (rather than just their binary approximations, as `double` and `float` do).

Comment: Why doesn't changing 1.09 to Double (1.09d) work but 1.09 to Decimal works?

Comment: @Alireza: double is also a floating point type. A float can also be named a single (<-> double). They both have the issue as described above.

Comment: @Alireza because decimal is designed to work with decimal systems, like most currencies.

Comment: To complete the comments and the answer: in C# double occupies 8 bytes while decimal occupies 12 bytes .

Comment: @Alireza Actually, a `decimal` occupies 16 bytes. You can verify this using `sizeof(decimal)`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel and p.s.w.g.: Just to clarify: `decimal`, `double` and `float` are all **floating point types**.  `decimal` has 29 decimal digits of precision; how many of them go before or after the decimal point is up to you, which makes it a **floating point** type. That's what "floating" means in this context.  The difference between `decimal` and `double` is that decimals represent a fraction with a power of ten in the denominator, and the other two types represent a fraction with a power of two in the denominator.

Comment: @EricLippert: Another difference between `float` and `double` on one hand, and `decimal` is that `float` supports a dynamic range which is orders of magnitude greater, and `double` goes hundreds of orders beyond that, and both also define three "sentinel" values for computations whose results exceed the range of `double` or are otherwise unrepresentable. This means that computations involving those types will always complete even if they yield no information beyond "value not computable".  The basic idea is in many cases like graphing a function...

Comment: ...it's often more efficient to let the computation run to completion, find out that a value couldn't be computed, and not plot that point, than it would be to either try to check all operands beforehand, or catch an exception that occurs during operation.

Answer (score 7):

Floating point arithmetic is not in base 10, it's in base 2.  the `double` type doesn't have an exact base-2 equivalent of `1.09`

To illustrate, if you put a break-point at the end of the following program

```
public static void Main()
{

    double test = 100 * 1.09;
}
```

than `test` would show up as `109.00000000000001`

Comment: 1.09 doesn't have a base 2 equivelant...... that can be represented with a finite number of digits

Comment: @Sam, true but not using the standard binary notation

Comment: @SamIam You can represent the rational number (note that this *is* rational) with "infinite" precision by just not actually calculating out the division and instead representing the number as a numerator and a denominator that are each of finite precision.

Comment: See my comment to the accepted answer. `decimal` is a floating point type.